# displaying error when date is after today date

Tags: angular

I'm creating a small app using Ngbdatepicker. Currently i am facing some issues. I wish to show an error when i have selected dates greater than today.

For example, if my birthday falls on may 21, i should not enter more than the current date.

If it falls beyond today date, i want to display an error

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="field_birthDate">Birth Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="field_birthDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="birthDate" ngbDatepicker #birthDateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="registerAccount.birthDate" [minDate]="ngbDatepickerConfig.minDate" [maxDate]="ngbDatepickerConfig.maxDate" required #birthDate="ngModel" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="birthDateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="birthDate.dirty && birthDate.invalid">
        <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="birthDate.errors.ngbDate?.requiredBefore || birthDate.errors.ngbDate?.requiredAfter">
            Your age must be between 18 and 100.
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above example does not match what i want. It should show error when Date is more than current date.

Comment: Then set maxDate to the current date. Why are you setting it to ngbDatepickerConfig.maxDate?

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to determine if the date is after today's (using TypeScript since you didn't specify):

```
isAfterToday(date) {
  let now = new Date() //today's date
  return date.getTime() > now.getTime();  //date.getTime() returns MS value of a date. So this will return which date is greater.
};
```

Then in your template, you can bind whether or not the error message div shows using this function:

```
<div *ngIf="isAfterToday(birthDate)">
    <small class="form-text text-danger" 
        ERROR: date supplied is invalid since it is after today's date.
    </small>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. maxDate issupposed to be an NgbDateStruct. Not a Date. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepicker